# My disk ran out of space after I configured maven archetype in eclipse preference

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, archetypes

I wanted to use jersey-archetype in a maven project  so I went to window-preference-maven tab in eclipse and checked options which are "Do not automatically update dependencies...", "Download Artifact Sources","Download Artifact Javadoc" and "Download repository index updates on startup" and press Apply button. But I found out they occupy a lot of disk space so I stopped in the middle of process. Problem is I can not recover my disk space because I do not know where those files are located.  Any advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MavenCentral indices are about 1-3GB. If this is too large for you, you should deactivate "Download repository index updates on startup".

The indices are somewhere in your workspace directory. To find them, use some program that measures disk space, e.g. WinDirStat. That way you will figure out the directory with more than 1GB.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I downloaded WinDirStat and solved problem. I found out a lot of cache files in  c://users/{myusername}/appdata/temp folder by the app you introduced. Thanks again..